# Free Winforms DataGrid or ListView with Grouping Capabilities

Tags: .net, winforms, listview, datagridview

Does anybody know a free datagrid or listview control with grouping and master/detail capabilites?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Best Free .Net DataGrid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190578/the-best-free-net-datagrid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this: 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/OutlookGrid.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article on the [Object ListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx) - a big enhancement over the ordinary Listview that would probably meet your requirements? XPTables is another which you can search for on the same site within **CodeProject**.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.